# View broken after upgrade to D6.33

Tags: views, upgrading

I'm working on upgrading an old site. I've just upgraded from 6.17 to 6.33. Most things seem to be working, including some views, however one view is throwing the error below. I agree that there's no `node_data_field_image` table in the db, but there isn't one in the pre-upgrade backup, either. Any ideas?

```
Unknown column 
    node_data_field_image.field_image_imceimage_title
in field list query: 

SELECT DISTINCT 
    node.nid AS nid, 
    node.title AS node_title, 
    node.uid AS node_uid, 
    node.type AS node_type, 
    node_revisions.format AS node_revisions_format, 
    node.created AS node_created, 
    node_data_field_image.field_image_imceimage_path AS node_data_field_image_field_image_imceimage_path, 
    node_data_field_image.field_image_imceimage_width AS node_data_field_image_field_image_imceimage_width, 
    node_data_field_image.field_image_imceimage_height AS node_data_field_image_field_image_imceimage_height, 
    node_data_field_image.field_image_imceimage_alt AS node_data_field_image_field_image_imceimage_alt, 
    node_data_field_image.field_image_imceimage_title AS node_data_field_image_field_image_imceimage_title, 
    node.vid AS node_vid, 
    node_revisions.body AS node_revisions_body, 
    node.sticky AS node_sticky, 
    DATE_FORMAT((FROM_UNIXTIME(node.created) + INTERVAL -14400 SECOND), &#039;%Y%m%d&#039;) AS node_created_day 
FROM node node 
LEFT JOIN node_revisions node_revisions 
ON node.vid = node_revisions.vid 
LEFT JOIN content_field_image node_data_field_image 
ON node.vid = node_data_field_image.vid 
WHERE (node.type in (&#039;news&#039;)) AND (node.status = 1 OR (node.uid = 1 AND 1 &lt;&gt; 0) OR 1 = 1) 
ORDER BY node_sticky DESC, node_created_day DESC LIMIT 0, 5 

in /home/rsage/rs_upgrade/sites/all/modules/views/includes/view.inc on line 810.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a backup of pre-upgrade version, how about your import your faulty view from there. The export-import feature in Views is usually very robust. If the import is successful, there is not point in banging your head as to why this error is coming.